# Worker nodes doesn't start correctly in Windows

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

- I have used the following steps to configure spark with
  standalone mode cluster in Windows,

  ```
  STEP 1: Download the spark from the following link
  [http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/spark/spark-1.3.1/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz][1]
  NOTE: I have install hadoop 2.5.2 and scala 2.10.4
  ```

STEP 2: Place spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz in F:/ directory

STEP 3: Extract this file using following command
Tar –xf spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz

STEP 4: Set the environment variables using the following commands to create the SPARK environment

```
   SET HADOOP_HOME=C:\Hadoop
   SET SCALA_HOME =C:\scala
   SET SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY =512m
   SET SPARK_HOME=F:\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4
   SET SPARK_MASTER_IP =synclapn2881
   SET SPARK_WORKER_CORES =2 
   SET SPARK_WORKER_DIR=F:\work\sparkdata
   SET SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES =4 
   SET SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY =1g
   SET Path=%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%Path%;
```

STEP 5:  Start the master node by using the following command
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master

STEP 6: Start the slave nodes using the following command
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://masternode:7077

Note:  Here masternode is localhostname

Actual result

Only 1 worker node started but I had set 4 instances,

```
         SET SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES =4
```

Refer the below screen shot

[image: SPARK WEB UI]

```
   Expected Result
   Create 4 Worker nodes, as I had SET SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES to 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In **windows**,
If you need 4 worker nodes you will have to execute **STEP 6** `4 times` in the same machine or 4 different machines
Start the slave nodes using the following command `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://masternode:7077`

Spark is not fully supported in windows.there are many issues i came accross trying to run spark on windows.
Even the start-slaves,start-master,start-slave script are not working in windows. I think its better to switch to linux.

from [spark documentation][1] 
**`Note: The launch scripts do not currently support Windows. To run a Spark cluster on Windows, start the master and workers by hand.`**

[1]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#Cluster Launch Scripts

Comment: Thank you..Is there a way to stop the workers. Closing the cmd window would do, but is there any other way to stop the workers?

Comment: In Linux you can run the stop-slaves.sh script in sbin folder but i don't know any equivalent in windows.